# Missing password-asking dialog popup on session via VNC-SSH

Tags: software-center, ssh, password, remote-desktop, vnc

I've almost got to have a remote Ubuntu Desktop working exactly as id it was a local session, but still can't solve a little issue wich is driving me crazy.

I have a remote machine with Ubuntu Desktop. I connect to it via VNC over SSH, and as I say "almost everything" works perfectly, except for a problem I'm not getting to solve and I can't figure out whether it's a problem regarding to permissions, to the own VNC (I don't think so), or whatever.

When, for example, I open the Ubuntu Software Center and try to install any program clicking on "Install", nothing happens, because the password-asking popup dialog never appears and so, Ubuntu can't install it.

It's not about installing packages, since I can do it with aptitude, or even executing the USC as root, but I would like to fix it in other way since I don't want to be executing programs as root when it's not the proper way.

My question is: Anybody knows why could this be happening and how to solve it?

Following with the example of installing some app with USC, the messages on /vat/log/syslog are these (no errors though, but never appears the password-asking dialog):

```
Apr  9 22:11:33 noname-machine dbus[551]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)
Apr  9 22:11:33 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Apr  9 22:11:33 noname-machine dbus[551]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Apr  9 22:11:33 noname-machine AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Apr  9 22:11:51 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'gameconqueror')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Apr  9 22:11:51 noname-machine AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/be384a2ba642461dbf4c33e8fdb363ec
```

(No messages on /var/log/auth.log)

Exactly the same problem when clicking "check" on Update Manager:

```
Apr  9 22:43:53 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Apr  9 22:43:53 noname-machine AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/35fae3fa030a497f8cb5405701c8d2d2
Apr  9 22:43:54 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Apr  9 22:43:54 noname-machine AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/13c03177009847dc9ce23c7913d44be7
Apr  9 22:43:55 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Apr  9 22:43:55 noname-machine AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e2db780da371473099d3655f76e2510d
Apr  9 22:43:55 noname-machine AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Apr  9 22:43:55 noname-machine AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/6f7a8a32df864d12b5372a11bc10481e
```

Anybody can see the problem?

(please excuse my english)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am having the same problem and have been searching for a resolution. That is how I came across this post. Also, the software updater opens up with the list of updates. I click install and it says waiting for password, but the password prompt never pops up and the updater just closes without doing anything. Right now I have to be basically be on the physical machine to install any software and do updates through the GUI or install the software through the command line. P.S. I meant to add this as a comment, but can't figure out how to delete this.

Answer (score -1):

This command should do it:

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

I had this problem when I moronically changed the owner of `/usr/lib` recursively.

Comment: will it, or won't it? 'Should' indicates that it is a stab in the air and the OP is looking for a definitive solution to the problem.

Comment: Eh, if it works for him I can change the wording to be more definitive, just worked in my situation.